# Library or advise on plotting box nodes interactively

Tags: plot, nodes, labview

I'm building an application that parses text files that contain information about specific nodes with incoming ports and outgoing ports that are interconnected. Doing some research there are some libraries but none of them support the exact characteristics needed.
this is what I'm trying to build and any language will do: Python, Perl, .net, etc.

One of the libraries I have found is GoDiagaram Node Classes
http://www.nwoods.com/components/dotnet/features-nodes.htm

[image]

The idea is to have boxes like so, interconnected and I should be able to click on one of them and link it to a new sub-diagram with more boxes contained in the one clicked.

[image]

Is there a counter part of these kind of charts that is opensource? and do these diagrams have a specific kind of name?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any specific details, since I never looked into this too closely, but here are some potential directions:

1. The data structure used for representing something like this is usually a graph (probably a directed graph). You could also try searching for graphical (or visual) programming languages. I seem to remember Pure Data as one that was relevant, but I never looked at it in detail.
2. Blender and VirtualDub both have a mode that's similar to this (the node editor and audio filters, respectively) and I believe both are open source, although I think neither has the option of having the nodes contain other nodes internally.
3. You could just use LabVIEW, which gives you the ability to create and edit LV code programmatically (search for "VI scripting"), but the code for that might not be very pretty and it's certainly not open source.

Comment: Scripting also requires a development license to run code. In other words, you can't distribute your application as an exe with scripting enabled and expect it to work with a generic Run Time Enviroment

Comment: That's what I have seen that LABView is a good option but is highly dependent on licenses. I will take a look at the other options you mention here @Yair

Comment: Actually, I heard there's a component you can install to have pretty much full access to VI server in an executable ([see here](https://decibel.ni.com/content/message/10063#10063)), but I never tried it and I'm assuming it's not supported in any way by NI and is not guaranteed to work for all VI server primitives, classes, methods or properties. In short, not something I would rely on.

Also, by what's said there, it looks like you're still expected to have a full license if you want to use it.